# Windows - Start Command and Protocol Handlers

Tags: batch-file, internet-explorer-9, protocols, command-prompt, dos

I am trying to create a web protocol for [Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com/) in IE9 on my local machine. I followed [Microsoft's add a protocol guide here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Unfortunately, I can't link the registry value for the `command` key straight to sublime since the protocol `sublime:` is appended to the address. So if I type `sublime:test.txt`, that whole string is passed to sublime and sublime doesn't know what to do with it.

So, I made a quick batch file to sanitize the string, `subl.bat`.

```
@echo off
echo %1%
pause
set str=%1
set str=%str:sublime:=%
start "" CALL "C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 2\sublime_text.exe" "%str%"
echo %str%
pause
```

The pauses are just for debugging and can be ignored. This batch file just strips out the `sublime:` part of the argument and then calls sublime passing the sanitized argument.

Now, when I change my `command` registry key to:

"C:\subl.bat" "%1"

and then try it out in Internet Explorer, I get the error `file path not found`. Well, if you try to run the batch file with the name in quotes and the argument in quotes using the `start` command, you actually need to prepend a string for window title and insert the `CALL` command after it, as in my batch file. My guess is that Internet Explorer is using a `start` command, or something like it, and since both arguments are in quotes, it's failing. I've tried changing the value to:

```
"" CALL "C:\subl.bat" "%1"
```

and

```
CALL "C:\subl.bat" "%1"
```

but neither worked. But, if I remove the quotes around the `%1` and the argument has no spaces, the protocol works! As soon as the parameter and program have quotes, it breaks.

I would really like to figure out why I can't write a protocol handler with spaces in both the program path and argument (surrounding each with quotes). Anyone have any ideas?

If you want to test this out, you do not need to reboot the computer each time you change the registry key, so it's easy to reproduce.

Oh, and the protocol works in Firefox however sublime tries to open `test` and `2` separately if the file was `test 2.log`. This is another instance where the `start` command behaves wonky because if you look at my batch file, I wrap the `str` variable in quotes so spaces should be preserved. If I open a prompt in the same directory as sublime and run sublime with the command line arg `c:\test 2.log` sublime properly opens just `test 2.log`, not `test` and `2` so I know it is an issue with the `start` command.

EDIT: I should add I've also tried URL encoding the path since the MSDN says the URI shouldn't contain special characters, but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 2):

Just from first read through, it would appear that the path is being misinterpreted.  Which leads me to believe it is a quotations issue. (Since batch scripts love quotations [sarcasm])  I think that you are having to many surrounding quotations.

Try this: (Added the tilde, also line 2 does not need the trailing `%`.)
The quotations around the set variable allow for special characters in the values.

```
@echo off
echo %1
pause
set "str=%~1"
set "str=%str:sublime:=%"
start "" CALL "C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 2\sublime_text.exe" "%str%"
echo %str%
pause
```

With: (Added a tilde)

```
CALL "C:\subl.bat" "%~1"
```

The tilde `~` will remove any surrounding quotations from the string (if any).